# Solving a difference equation with two variables

Tags: recurrence-relations, transformation, discrete-calculus

Consider the following difference equation:
$$
{c_1}{a_{n + 3}} + {c_2}{a_{n + 2}} + {c_3}{b_{n + 2}} + {c_4}{p_{n + 2}} + {c_5}{p_{n + 1}} + {c_6}{p_{n + 3}} + {c_7}{p_{n + 3/2}} + {c_8}{p_{n + 5/2}} = 0
$$
where the unknowns are:
$$
{a_{n}},{b_{n}}
$$
and are to be determined in terms of $${p_{n}},{p_{n+1}},...$$
Is there any way to obtain the unknowns by transforming the difference equation into an algebraic one? or transfer the unknowns from points *n+3*, *n+2*, ... to *n*?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Those terms $p_{n+3/2}$ and $p_{n+5/2}$ are peculiar, to say the least…

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Let's ignore those terms. what is the general way to handle these kind of equations?